# What events can I catch when the user leaves a GXT grid?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have a web app that uses GXT (version 1.2.2) grids extensively. I'd like to warn the user if they make changes but don't save.

When I use the grid in a popup dialog, the only way for the user to leave is via a button (either Close or OK). If I add a SelectionListener to the Close button, I can do my "isDirty()" check and warn the user.

If I am not using a dialog, the restriction for leaving the page isn't there. The user can click on a side menu, select a different tab, hit a refresh or next page button that we have on each page. I could listen for an event on everyone of those, but is there an easier way? Something like a "before unload" event that gets fired?

Answer (score 0):

[Window.addCloseListener](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addWindowCloseListener(com.google.gwt.user.client.WindowCloseListener))

Or in GWT 1.6:

[Window.addCloseHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#addCloseHandler(com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.CloseHandler))

You cannot prevent the window from closing, but you can prompt the user to click cancel which will leave the page open. You can also perform a last-chance save operation after the user chooses to confirm the window close, but before your page is unloaded.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, I assume since the window isn't closing. I'm just going to another grid or tab or page.

Comment: I see. If the Grid is indeed unloading, then your only hope is hooking the onDetach() method on the the Widget. There's no listener so you'd have to overload it within a subclass. If the tab is changed, but the grid remains hidden, then you're completely out of luck and must listen to everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Window.addListener(Events.Close,
     new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
          public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
                //Do something
          }
});
```

***or***

```
Window.addListener(Events.Detach,
         new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
              public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
                    //Do something
              }
    });
```